# hook_node_insert, hook_entity_insert, hool_node_presave not triggering

Tags: 7, hooks

I just got a  drupal 7 site with a custom theme handed over to me.

I have to do some stuff when a curtain content type is created by a user, but i am so far unable to get any related hooks working.

So far i tried to add the following to the tempalte.php file

```
function MYTHEME_node_insert($node) {}

function MYTHEME_entity_insert($entity, $type) {}

function MYTHEME_node_presave($node) {}
```

Changing MYTHEME to the name of my theme. 
I doubbledchecked and the template.php file is used.

Answer (score 2):

Only certain theme-related hooks, and alter hooks, can be implemented by a theme. The hooks you're trying to implement aren't in that list, as they're unrelated to theming.

You'll need to create a custom module and implement he hooks there instead.

Comment: Yeah, just realized. Thank you for the answer though. Have a great weekend!